# How to group and order an API response

Tags: java, api, jackson

My API is very generic, it's meant to serve several different experiences. In my Java controller, I make a call to get the data and read it using Jackson Tree. What I need to do is group and order the results in the way I want it displayed in the UI. I'll know the ordering and grouping I want before the response comes back, so what's the best way to do that?

Here's a generic example of my returned JSON:

```
{
    "callerId": "1234567890",
    "data": {
        "type": "APIResponseObject",
        "dataObj": [
            {
                "APICode": "MY_API_CODE",
                "dataCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "Generic Label 5",
                        "code": "ITEM_CODE_5"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Generic Label 4",
                        "code": "ITEM_CODE_4"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Generic Label 3",
                        "code": "ITEM_CODE_3"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Generic Label 2",
                        "code": "ITEM_CODE_2"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Generic Label 1",
                        "code": "ITEM_CODE_1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And here's an example of how I want the JSON to look when it's returned to the UI:

```
{
    "callerId": "1234567890",
    "data": {
        "type": "APIResponseObject",
        "dataObj": [
            {
                "APICode": "MY_API_CODE",
                "dataCategories": [
                    {
                        "group1":[
                        {
                            "label": "Generic Label 1",
                            "code": "ITEM_CODE_1"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Generic Label 2",
                            "code": "ITEM_CODE_2"
                        },
                        ]
                    },
                    "group2":[
                        {
                            "label": "Generic Label 3",
                            "code": "ITEM_CODE_3"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Generic Label 4",
                            "code": "ITEM_CODE_4"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Generic Label 5",
                            "code": "ITEM_CODE_5"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And this is the snippet from my RestController where I'm using Jackson to read it and store it in a JsonNode:

```
    //read json file data to String
    byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(path);

    //create ObjectMapper instance
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    //convert json string to object
    MyObject data = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, MyObject.class);

    // re-order the response based on a template of some kind
    // Look into @JsonPropertyOrder...which allows us to specify
    // the order of properties (may be on serialization only)

    // parse json into JsonNode so we can use tree model
    JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonData);
```

And then I would pass that *rootNode* into some other class like:

```
// Now pass rootNode into some class that returns the JSON
    // in the correct order that I want. Something like 
    // *TransformJsonByType*. That accepts JSON in one form and returns
    // it in the form that I want. 

    public class TransformJsonByType{
       // Accepts JSON in one format and spits it out in another using 
       // Jackson Tree Traversal
    }
```

My POJOs are fine. I think the only thing I need to figure out is this *MyObjectParser* class.

So I know that I want ITEM_CODE_1 and ITEM_CODE_2 grouped together and shown first, and items 3, 4, and 5 to also be grouped together and shown last.

I'm not necessarily looking for a complete solution but I do need a starting point, please. How can I mutate a JSON response before returning it to my UI? And in addition, how do I make sure it aheres to these rules?

I'm a newbie Java programmer and am just getting started in this area. Thanks for any helpful tips.

Comment: Why was this moved? I didn't want to put it here because the question is open-ended.

Comment: It will be better to make the group where you are creating the json in the first place. Can you share the code where you are building the json?

Comment: I've included the snippet above where I'm using Jackson to retrieve the JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a customized @JsonGetter in your MyObject implementation

```
@JsonGetter("dataCatagories")
public List<String, List<ChildObj>> getDataCategoriesJSON() {
    List<String, List<ChildObj>>  json = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ChildObj co : this.dataCategories) {
        // TODO: whatever logic there
    }
}
```

It might solve the problem, but it's the worst solution. You should instead of define your POJO with correct structure and massage data before put into it.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with my POJOs. I think the missing piece is this "MyObjectParser" class (that I mention above) where it accepts the original JSON and mutates it to the way that I need.